# Teams not displaying email sent via SendGrid

Tags: email, microsoft-teams, sendgrid

I'm trying to post to a Teams channel via the email address using SendGrid. However, the emails I send via SendGrid are not appearing. I ended up adding my personal email address as well, and I do receive that one as well as seeing the Teams email address in the To: field. I can also see in SendGrid dashboard that the email was send **and delivered** to the Teams channel address. I have validated that this address is correct, and have also posted via my non-work email address to that channel, so I know it's not because of a typo or an external email address. My guess is that there is something in the email meta data that is making Teams reject the email? Anyone have ideas 1) why Teams won't post the email coming from SendGrid and 2) how I might modify my request in SendGrid so that it works? Also, alternative suggestions on sending emails (for free) from nodejs are welcome.

Here is the code I'm using to send the email for reference:

```js
        var msg = {
            to: ['TEAMSCHANNELID@amer.teams.ms','mycompanyemail@company.com'], // ChatBot Support Team, General Channel
            from: 'noreply@chatbotapimonitor.com',
            subject: `Service Interruption Notice: API ${test} is down (via ${functionName})`,
            text: `API ${test} failed with error ${error}`,
            html: `API ${test} failed with error ${error}`
        };
        try {
            await sgMail.send(msg);
        } catch (err) {
            context.log(err);
        }
```

Comment: Why not just use Incoming Webhooks?

Comment: Not enabled for our tenant :(

Comment: Perhaps your organization limits the sending ability to only certain domains? Someone with admin rights can check it under [Teams settings](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/company-wide-settings/teams-settings) => Email integration

Comment: Sad to hear. What about Connectors?

Comment: @RobertDyjas actually it seems like the issue may be that the From and the "actual" From are not the same (in Outlook I can see Sent via sendgrid.net after the from address). I'm guessing Teams does not allow messages to be posted if the address does not match. I'm guessing enabling domain authentication in SendGrid might fix the issue, but I'm unlikely to get approval for that unfortunately...

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I do have connectors but the only ones available are not very helpful. I do believe I can sideload a new connector though, assuming that it can be done the same way as the actual Teams apps. I might have a look at making my own incoming webhook connector, which as crazy as it sounds just may work.

Comment: yeah that's what I meant - making your own Connector app and side-loading. If you go ahead with it, please let me know - would love to know how it works out

Comment: Yes exactly making your own Connector would work. Please let us know.

Comment: This is still a problem with sendgrid in 2023, even when the domain is fully validated on the sendgrid account with correct SPF and DKIM configuration. It won't even accept messages that originate from sendgrid, go to Exchange Online distribution group, which then includes a Teams email address. No good workarounds.

Comment: In addition to the "workaround" of using webhooks, I have found sending emails with Microsoft Graph API to be far superior for organizations that have that capability. It took me a while to get a approval for an AAD account with email send capabilities, but once I got that and a generic email address it has greatly simplified or programmatic email sending workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Teams won't accept incoming emails if the From address domain does not match the actual "sent from" domain. I recognized this by the "Sent via sendgrid.net" message I saw in Outlook when the emails were sent to me as well.

I was able to get the out of the box Incoming Webhooks enabled, and using that instead of SendGrid emails got around the problem. I got the URL from the webhook configuration and then was able to call it like so:

```js
        var headers = { 'ContentType': 'application/json'}
        var body = {
            '@context': 'https://schema.org/extensions',
            '@type': 'MessageCard',
            'themeColor': 'FF0000',
            'title':`API ${test} is down: Service Interruption Notice`,
            'text': `API ${test} failed with error ${error}.\n\r\n\rReported by ${functionName} during test started on ${now.toString()}`
        };
        var res = await request({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            json: body,
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        });
```

The themeColor doesn't appear in all channels, but I have it working as a nice red/green indicator on Teams desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your organization limits the sending ability to only certain domains? Someone with admin rights can check it under Teams settings => Email integration

yeah that's what I meant - making your own Connector app and side-loading. If you go ahead with it, please let me know - would love to know how it works out

Yes exactly making your own Connector would work.